# initialize DOM after json call

Tags: jquery, json, dom

button dont'work whit append. how i can initialize for work?

```
              var  content  = '<div class="row mt-5 bg-white rounded  border "><div class="col-10 mt-2  "> <h5>'+ data[i].name + '</h5> ';
                   content += ' <p>' + data[i].description + '</p>';
                   content += '</div> <div class="col-2"><button type="button"  id="btn-action" class="btn btn-success btn-lg float-right w-80 m-2" >CTA</button></div></div>';


                $('div.lista').append(content);
```

Comment: button did not work means what?

Comment: when i click no action for the button

Comment: Well it is a button. Where is the event?

Comment: What is the button meant to do @RobyEm?

Comment: $("#btn-action").click(function(){
      alert("ciao");
    });

Comment: this is a part of code in json that fill dinamically html, but after json call button not work.

Comment: When or how do you add that click handler? This may be a case where the handler can't find the target because the target and its id did not exist when you set up the handler. If so, you'll need a delegated handler.